# Extensions don't show up in VS Code -- Cannot find

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code ver 1.25.1, this computer is iMac. I don't use this computer many time so I just figured out yesterday I couldn't find extensions in VS code. There such results is empty. Is it VS code bug or I missed something?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The VScode Marketplace website has been down all day. I just tried again but still couldn't get on. This is the site where VScode extensions are stored and downloaded. I suppose they are working on restoring service.

Comment: Thanks, so perhaps it's temporary problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure your problem is related with VSCode downtime :)

[image: Visual Studio is back]

More information about this: https://twitter.com/code/status/1037215136812032001